# "Do only use" Or "only use"

Tags: imperatives, do

Which of these sentences is correct?

1. "Do only use in [an] emergency case"
2. "Only use in [an] emergency case"

Comment: This reads like a notice, because it's abbreviated -- it has no explicit object. *Do* is never used for emphasis in notices. If it's not a notice, then you need some sort of object: *this, it, the door,* whatever.

Comment: The conventional phrasing is "use only in case of emergency".

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct as *do* can be used for emphasis

> In the present simple, the auxiliaries do and does (in the third person singular) followed by the bare infinitive form of the main verb can be used in affirmative sentences to express emphasis.

[Grammaring.com](http://www.grammaring.com/the-auxiliaries-do-and-does-for-emphasis)

Comment: I'd be glad if somebody explained to me, if "Do use only in [an] emergency case" is correct too or only "Do only use in [an] emergency case" is correct?